# What does generic typing to a new instance achieve? 

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have noticed someone has done this in C# - notice the new()

```
public class MyClass<T> where T: new(){

//etc

}
```

What does this achieve?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This constrains the generic `MyClass<T>` to only work with `T` instances that have an available parameterless constructor.  This allows you to safely use the following expression within the type

```
new T()
```

Without the `new` constraint this would not be allowed because the CLR couldn't verify the type `T` had an applicable constructor.

Comment: Fantastic. That helps me more than I expected

Answer (score 4):

It means that T must have a public parameterless constructor. For example (out of MSDN), the following creation of a new T object must be possible:

```
class ItemFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

For more info, please see [new constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5%28VS.80%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

It enables you to type:

```
T obj = new T();
```

which would generate a compiler error without the `new()` clause.